# Where Are MySQL DB Backups Stored

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I just ran `mysqldump --all-databases > dump-$( date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S' ).sql -u root -p` but I can not locate the database location on my `Ubuntu 16.04` system.  What location did this database get created in?

Comment: They should be in whatever directory you were in you ran that command. To be more explicit about location next time you could use `mysqldump --all-databases > ~/dump-$( date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S' ).sql -u root -p` which will dump it in your home directory.

Comment: I was in my home directory user123@ubuntu: but the backup is not in my Home directory

Comment: I see the issue now and have written an answer explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `>` symbol redirects stdout from the command preceding the symbol to the file location following the symbol `mycommand > outputfile.txt`. In your case you need to pass the username and password flags to the `mysqldump` command. In your attempt you are putting the flags on the wrong side of the `>` redirect.

```
mysqldump --all-databases -u root -p > dump-$( date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S' ).sql
```

Since a directory wasn't specified for that file it will write to whatever directory you are currently in. You can be more explicit by specifying the directory:

```
 mysqldump --all-databases -u root -p > ~/mysql_backups/dump-$( date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S' ).sql
```